# Ransack Search Id and Strings Together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack, predicates

I am trying to search using Ransack but having issue when i am trying to search id and string together like

> :id_or_title_or_user_username_cont

It produces the error

> ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer ~~* integer

I have also tried this

> :id_eq_or_title_or_user_username_cont

it produces following error

> undefined method `id_eq_or_title_or_user_username_cont' for Ransack::Search

What is the appropriate way of searching id and strings together using ransack other than custom predicates or with custom predicates ?

Comment: The possible solutions have been added to ransack wiki https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/using-ransackers#4-convert-an-integer-database-field-to-a-string-in-order-to-be-able-to-use-a-cont-predicate-instead-of-the-usual-eq-which-works-out-of-the-box-with-integers-to-find-all-records-where-an-integer-field-id-in-this-example-contains-an-input-string

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
ransacker :id_to_s do 
  Arel.sql("regexp_replace(to_char(\"#{table_name}\".\"id\", '9999999'), ' ', '', 'g')")
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am bit confused here how i am suppose to use it in search field ? Like the predicate in my question can be used as 
<%= f.search_field :id_eq_or_title_or_user_username_cont %>
can you please elaborate it futher. It will be very appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: So @FakhirShad if you are confused then you should not accept this as an answer.

Comment: Check out the date of my comment and the date when answer was accepted @zozo

Answer (score 3):

I needed a bit more details than the other answers gave, so here it is.

A `_cont` search on an integer column doesn't work because LIKE queries wouldn't work on such columns. You need to cast the column from integer to string for your query to work. In your model, you can do that with a `ransacker` call:

```rb
# app/models/your_model.rb
class YourModel

  # For Postgres
  ransacker :id do
    Arel.sql("to_char(\"#{table_name}\".\"id\", '99999999')")
  end

  # For MySQL
  ransacker :id do
    Arel.sql("CONVERT(`#{table_name}`.`id`, CHAR(8))")
  end
```

You can then use a search predicate like `id_cont`.

Answer (score 2):

The following post [Finding records by ID with Ransack](https://www.joshmcarthur.com/2013/10/29/code-snippet-18-oct-2013.html) provides an answer:

```
  # Cast the ID column to a string in PostgreSQL
  # when searching with Ransack.
  # Allows searches with _cont and _eq predicates.
  # From https://github.com/ernie/ransack/issues/224
  ransacker :id do
    Arel.sql("to_char(\"#{table_name}\".\"id\", '99999999')")
  end
```

The provided answer originally comes from this github issue: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/224

Answer (score 0):

Small update as the answers above correct, but I found they had the side effect of causing normal results (e.g full list, no search) to be Ordered by the string value of ID, so - 1,10,11,12...etc...2,20,21...3,30 etc instead of 1,2,3,4...

So combining both ideas above, can search by ID but still sort by Int ID

In the Model create a stringified version of ID for ransack

```
ransacker :id_as_str do
  Arel.sql("to_char(\"#{self.table_name}\".\"id\", '99999999')")
end
```

And in the form

```
<%= f.search_field :id_as_str_or_some_other_stuff_cont, placeholder: "Search..." %>
```